# Download pdf in visualforce page using iframe with dynamic file name

Tags: pdf, iframe, salesforce, visualforce

I am generating a pdf dynamically from a third party and display it on Iframe in visualforce page, I just want when the user clicks on the download button in Iframe then the file should be download with a dynamic name not by "download.pdf".
I am using this code snippet to provide pdf value to iframe in script of vf page, here "result" contains base64 of PDF.

```
j$('<iframe>', {
                       src: 'data:Application/pdf;base64,'+result,
                       id:  'idOfIframe',
                       class: 'non-hover',
                       scrolling: 'no'
                    }).appendTo('#idOFDiv');
```